# How to parse a text like XML to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, xml, json, parsing, text-parsing

I created a function to do this.

```
var text="adsf [name]Victor[/name] dummytext [name]Elliot[/name] asdf [name]Jake[/name] asdf [foo]bar[/foo]";

alert( readTags(text,'name') ); //Victor,Elliot,Jake
alert( readTags(text,'foo') ); //bar
```

but now I like to implement a function that receive a string like this

```
[person]
    [name]jake[/name]
    [age]12[/age]
[/person]
```

and return a object like this

```
var object={};
object['person']={};
object['name']='jake';
object['age']='12';
return(object);
```

but I don't know how to loop through the text. How to deal with starting and ending tags?
 like

```
[tag] [tag]value[/tag] [/tag]
```

I thought to find starting tag from left and ending tag from the right using `indexOf('[tag]')` and `lastindexOf('[/tag]')`

but doesn't work in this situation

```
[tag]value[/tag] [tag]value[/tag]
```

this is the previous function

```
function readTags(str,property){

    var beginTag='['+property+']';
    var endTag='[/'+property+']';

    var values=new Array(0);

    while(str.indexOf(beginTag)!=-1){
        values[values.length]=strBetween(str,beginTag,endTag);
        str=str.substring(str.indexOf(endTag)+endTag.length);
    }
    return(values);
}

function strBetween(string,strBegin,strEnd){    //StrBetween("abcdef","b","e")  //return "cd"

    var posBegin, posEnd;

    posBegin=string.indexOf(strBegin);
    string=string.substring(posBegin + strBegin.length);
    posEnd=string.indexOf(strEnd);
    string=string.substring(0,posEnd);

    if ((posBegin==-1)||(posEnd==-1)){
        return(null);
    }else{
        return(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this.  Use [JSON](http://json.org/) instead.

Comment: @PointedEars I'm using blogs to host content that can be grabbed by robots like this, almost all add trash to JSON or doesn't allow XML or <> tags

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a good reason *not* to use [JSON](http://www.json.org/), don't do this. JSON handles all of those problems very well and can be floated around from server to client and vice versa quite easily.

But since this seems fun, I'll try and see if I can whip up an answer.

---

Since your structure resembles XML, just replace the brackets with `<` and `>` and parse it like XML:

```
text = text.replace('[', '<').replace(']', '>');

if (typeof DOMParser != "undefined") {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xml = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/xml');
} else {
  var xml = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
  xml.async = 'false';
  xml.loadXML(text); 
}
```

Now `xml` holds a `DOMDocument` that you can parse:

```
xml.getElementsByTagName('person').childnodes;
```

---

Try this possibly-working code (didn't test):

```
function createObject(element) {
  var object = {};

  if (element.childNodes.length > 0) {
    for (child in element.childnodes) {
      object[element.tagName] = createObject(child);
    }

    return object;
  } else {
    return element.nodeValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: smart solution! it's cross browser? now I think I can use `getElementsByTagName("*")` to loop all elements and generate a object. I'm right?

Comment: The second part of the `if` handles IE, which is a problem in every instance. As for the second part, sure. I'd personally stick with `childnodes` and `tagName` to iterate. It'll simplify your task.

Comment: (actually, that was my next idea) Do not use `window` here; use `this` if you must, but better `if (typeof DOMParser != "undefined")`. Declare `text`, `parser`, `xml` etc. variables with `var`. Returns a `NodeList`, so must be `getElementsByTagName("person")[0]`. Must be `childNodes` (case-sensitive).

DOMParser is pretty cross-browser by now. For IE/MSHTML you have the second branch; requires enabled ActiveX support, though.

Passing "*" will return a NodeList of all elements. But that will be flat, so you cannot build your object from it. You need to traverse the tree. E4X can help here.

Comment: @PointedEars: Thanks for the tips. I included what I could.

Comment: @PointedEars flat list will be a problem, but I think I can use a function that I wrote in the past to travel a tree, using recursion to get deep into a "multi dimensional array", but I have no idea if it will works.

Comment: @Vitimtk: Try my code, if you wish. I think it does what you want.

Comment: @Blender I am still seeing problems. Should I list them here or just diddle it?

Comment: @PointedEars: What problems do you see?

Comment: @Blender Missing declarations, no global replace, missing `try`-`catch` for `ActiveXObject`, missing `0` property access, all-lowercase `childnodes`, `for`-`in` iteration over host object, plain `nodeValue` instead of `textContent` (emulation).

Comment: xml parser works fine, but I'm trying to get creatObject function to work about 2 hours, debuging in safari, `for (child in element.childnodes) {` should be `childNodes` instead `childnodes` and the recursion `createObject(child);` should be `createObject(element.childNodes[child]);` but sometimes I get `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'element.childNodes.length')` any ideas?

Comment: I asked a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109823/javascript-create-object-from-dom

Answer (score 1):

I thought this would be interesting to do without a third-party parser, so I built me a simple one:

```
function parse(code)
{
  var obj = {},
      cur = obj,
      stack = [];

  code.replace(/\[([^\]]+)\]|([^\[]*)/g, function (match, tagName, text) {
    if (tagName)
    {
      if (tagName.charAt(0) == "/")
      {
        /* end tag */
        cur = stack.pop();
      }
      else
      {
        /* start tag */
        stack.push(cur);
        cur = cur[tagName] = {};
      }
    }
    else
    {
      cur["#text"] = text;
    }
  });

  return obj;
}

var obj = parse(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON <=> XML http://code.google.com/p/x2js/