# JavaScript: Create Object from DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, object

I'm trying to make a walkable DOM tree, like so:

**Input**:

```
<div>
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
</div>
```

**Output (*Python-like*)**:

```
{'div': [{'span': 'Foo'},
         {'span': 'Bar'}]}
```

I'd like to traverse it like so:

```
elements['div']['span']; // Output is "Foo".
```

My current code is this:

```
function createObject(element) {
  var object = {};

  if (element.childNodes.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
      object[element.tagName] = createObject(element.childNodes[i]);
    }

    return object;
  } else {
    return element.nodeValue;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work (the loop doesn't run). Could anyone help with this problem?

Comment: This line has a bug: `object[element.tagName] = createObject(element.childNodes[i]);`, In your example the second span will wipe out the first one, as `element.tagName` is not unique.

Comment: are you sure you mean tagName and not nodeName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What should happen?

```
If no child         {name: value}
if childs           {name: [
                        {childname: childvalue}
                    ]}
```

Following that logic, this is the result. Note `nodeName` should be used instead of `tagName`. Text nodes are also selected, which have `nodeName` #Text`. If you want to only select elements, add`if(element.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1)`:

```
function createObject(element) {
  var object, childs = element.childNodes;

  if (childs.length > 0) {
    object = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
        //Uncomment the code if you want to ignore non-elements
        // if(childs.nodeType == 1) {
            object.push(createObject(childs[i]));
        // }
    }

    return object;
  } else {
    object = {};
    object[element.nodeName] = element.nodeValue;
    return object;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to test this, it looks like the main problem is your `for ... in` loop - it doesn't work the same way in Javascript it does in Python.

```
for (child in element.childnodes)
```

should probably be an iterator-based loop:

```
for (var x=0, child; x<element.childNodes.length; x++) {
    child = element.childNodes[x];
    // etc
}
```

You'll also get text nodes you don't expect, and should check `child.nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE` before recursing.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong code chunk :P I did have a normal `for` loop going, but it was not being looped over at all (all the conditions were met, though).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like childNodes.length differs between browsers, maybe you should use hasChildNodes instead?

Also, did you use firebug (or any js debugger) to see if element was correctly filled in?

Edit : **I found what is wrong.** You can't create object of objects. Instead, you have to create array of objects. Check if you have childNodes, and create an object if there is none. Otherwise, create an array.

Just like your python-like output shows :-)

Comment: You can definitely create an "object of objects" (that is, an object which properties store references to other objects). It's just a matter of the algorithm.

Comment: @Florian Thanks for replying my question. I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)